# Eclipse features in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, eclipse

This might of been asked elsewhere (seems like a useful topic) but searches turned up nothing.

One feature I love in Eclipse when programming Java is that I don't have to worry about putting in the import statements and any missed functions from interfaces that I am implementing them - if I do miss them a simple click from a list implements them for me.

Now I am working in VisualStudio2008 with C# I am really missing that functionality. I was wondering if the functionality is in there, but buried or can be purchased through a 3rd party?

Thanks.

Comment: I've rolled back to the original one as I feel that the version of visual studio is important. Some extensions coming out are VS2008 only  so the version you require is important.

Comment: please use the full expansion then, many of us don't have a clue what "vs" stands for on its own, and "vs2008" is really uninformative.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a call to something from one of the standard libraries (or a library that is referenced by the project) which isn't "using", the intellisence will show a mark below the keyword, like so:

[image]

Hover over it and open the menu, and you can choose to add the "using" keyword, or make the typename explicit, like so:

[image]

And it then adds the "using" to the top of the file.

[image]

Comment: ctrl+shift+f11 || alt+enter [enter] //for Re#er

Answer (score 2):

you have to pay for this feature. Look at Resharper 4.0 from JetBrains. It is a perfect solution for me.

Comment: There are non-pay alternatives.